# Что такое $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], Почему там полный адрес сторонних сайтов?

Tags: php

Начал собирать простенькую статистику на сайте. Решил в том числе отслеживать на какой странице именно находится пользователь (по какому запросу пришел). Для этой цели использую $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].
В итоге получаю такие варианты:

/about или /support *- ок, это и ожидалось*

http://www.bing.com или www.baidu.com:443 **- WTF?**

Откуда берутся эти адреса сторонних сайтов в запросе?

И как получить корректный адрес, по которому перешел ко мне пользователь или робот.

Comment: Видимо по теме https://habrahabr.ru/post/183668/

Answer (score 2):

**Что такое $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?**

Это адрес который был передан для того, чтобы получить доступ к странице с которой пришел запрос.

**Для отсеивания роботов** я бы рекомендовал передавать через ajax какую нибудь переменную т.к. большинство роботов не запускают джаваскрипт на сайте. Можно сгенерировать токен пользователя на стороне PHP (предварительно собрав нужную информацию о пользователе из массива $_SERVER['...']) и затем запускать скрипт который в фоновом режиме передает на сервер что "на сайте не робот".